How much vertical space is there before equation in minipage
I try to remove the vertical space before the equation inside the first minipage

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{equation*}
        a=n
    \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
}
%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
   $a=n$
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document} 


The way that skip before a displayed equation is determined is rather complicated and in general depends on a multitude of parameters. You can find an extensive survey of all the parameters in How exactly is spacing in and around a multiline math environment determined?
In your rather academic case the situation is relatively simple. The space that you have to compensate by is -\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip+1ex. This only has this simple form, however, because \lineskip isn't active and the math ex height is actually the same as the text ex height.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
    \vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip+1ex\relax}
    \begin{equation*}
      a=n
    \end{equation*}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\end{document} 



You can just precede the equation* environment with \noindent, but if the display is the only thing in the minipage you also need something that forces the entire width.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
%% force the whole line width
\hrule height0pt width \linewidth
\noindent\begin{equation*}
        a=n
    \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
   $a=n$
\end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
}

% check the width
\rule{\dimeval{50pt+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}}{0.4pt}

\end{document}


Without the \hrule instruction, you'd get

(for not easy to explain reasons regarding TeX \vbox constructions).
You decide whether you really want a minipage.

what is the consequence of forgetting the comment char %. I don't see any difference

@HafidBoukhoulda Remove them and compare closely with the rule below.

Yes I see! How should it be explained?

@HafidBoukhoulda The endline would count as a space.
